# tempdb usage in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I have a `SELECT INTO` statement writing to a database which is in SIMPLE recovery mode, and is not tempdb. Will this use tempdb at all?

The SQL is something like

```
USE TGTDB
GO

SELECT * INTO DestinationTable FROM SRCDB.dbo.SourceTable
GO
```

Will this use tempdb at all? We are running into contention issues.

Comment: How have you determined that the contention is in `tempdb`?

Answer (score 2):

First, run your query and make a note of your SESSION_ID.

Then, run these two queries to see how much TempDB space your original query is using. Be sure to update them with your SESSION_ID.

```
-- TempDB session usage
select * 
from sys.dm_db_session_space_usage
where session_id = 123
go

-- TempDB task usage
select *
from sys.dm_db_task_space_usage t
where session_id = 123
go
```

Also, run this query to show us the layout of your TempDB. Please post the results.

```
use tempdb
go
exec sp_helpfile
go
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it could since it will use `tempdb` sometimes for internal objects to hold intermediate results.

I would suggest that you go to Books online and search for `tempdb` and then read the section on troubleshooting. It has some suggestions and queries for how to find out what is causing your `tempdb` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tembdb is used to store temporary objects (cursors, tables, etc.) and as a work area to spool and sort records in certain situations.

I would have expected there to be no tempdb usage for the simple query in your example (unless the source table is actually a view).

Can you elaborate on the "contention issues" you're experiencing?